# numpy: Find non-overlapping blocks in square matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra

Introducing my problem with an example: I have a numpy matrix

```
     1 . . 1 .
     . 1 . . 1
A =  . . 1 . 1 
     1 . . 1 .
     . 1 1 . 1
```

where I've used dots to represent zeros for better visual clarity. I am free to reorder the rows and columns of the matrix as long as I keep track of it, which reveals that it can be represented in block form:

```
     1 1 . . .
     1 1 . . .
B =  . . 1 1 . 
     . . 1 1 1
     . . . 1 1
```

Obviously, this matrix consists of two non-overlapping blocks,

```
1 1         1 1 .
1 1   and   1 1 1
            . 1 1
```

with indices `B[0:2,0:2]` and `B[2:5,2:5]`.

Is there a general way to find the number and indices of all such non-overlapping blocks in the original matrix `A`? `A` can have different sizes, but will always be square, symmetric, and only consist of entries 1 and 0.

I have a vague feeling that there might be some sort of clever linear algebra trick to do this, but so far I can't see it.

Comment: This is essentially finding the connected components of a graph... (think of your matrix as an adjacency matrix)

Comment: Graphs and connectivity, eh? Thanks for the keywords. Thus the googling commences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Julien in the comments for mentioning graphs and connections. After some digging around, here's what I have come up with.

Assuming we start with the "unordered" matrix `A` from my original post:

```
import scipy
import scipy.sparse
import scipy.ndimage

# transform A to sparse format;
# use scipy graph methods to reorder it into "contiguous" block form
B = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(A)
permut = scipy.sparse.csgraph.reverse_cuthill_mckee(B)
B = B[permut,:][:,permut].toarray() # transform back to normal numpy array

# using scipy.ndimage methods, relabel all "non-touching" features 
# in matrix B and extract their index slices
B, num_features = scipy.ndimage.label(B)
slices = scipy.ndimage.find_objects(B)
```

`B` at the end of this code snippet (with zeros represented by dots):

```
     1 1 . . .
     1 1 1 . .
B =  . 1 1 . .
     . . . 2 2
     . . . 2 2
```

`slices`:

```
[(slice(0, 3, None), slice(0, 3, None)),
 (slice(3, 5, None), slice(3, 5, None))]
```

which represents the blocks I asked for, just in different order.

Documentation of the used methods:

[csgraph.reverse_cuthill_mckee](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.reverse_cuthill_mckee.html) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill%E2%80%93McKee_algorithm))
[ndimage.label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html#scipy.ndimage.label)
[ndimage.find_objects](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.find_objects.html)